# .htaccess is not redirecting from old url to new url 3

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new in `.htaccess`. I have read the documentation, but couldn't make the redirect rule work.

I want `RewriteRule` for following

```
http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/59393/the-grounds-of-alexandria.htm
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria
```

I have tried out this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]/(.*)$ ^(.*)/(.*)/$ [R=301,L]
```

Also how can u get the subdomain and put it to the front of all links, like this

```
http://sydney.mywebsite.com/restaurants/59393/the-grounds-of-alexandria.htm
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/sydney/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria
```

but no result.

Comment: You want `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/\d+/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: do i need to write any RewriteCond for it?

Comment: If you enter `http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria` in browser, does it load correct page content (since id is missing from URL now).

Comment: wait, isn't your code mean, that if i enter http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/59393/the-grounds-of-alexandria.htm it will open this http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite this is simple:

```
http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/59393/the-grounds-of-alexandria.htm
to
http://mywebsite.com/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria
```

Your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]/(.*)$ ^(.*)/(.*)/$ [R=301,L]` is too global for the urls. Second of all you just say [0-9] with means only one digit.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[0-9]+/([^.]+)\.htm$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Try this one ;)

---

**Edit (for second question):**

```
http://sydney.mywebsite.com/restaurants/59393/the-grounds-of-alexandria.htm
to 
http://mywebsite.com/sydney/restaurants/the-grounds-of-alexandria
```

Sure ;) There you have to work with RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^\.]+)\.mywebsite\.com/([^/]+)/[0-9]+/([^.]+)\.htm
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mywebsite.com/%1/%2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

For explanation, the %1-3 can be used from the previous match to be used in the RewriteRule Statement. This should work for every subdomain and only for subdomains. If you want a specific subdomain you can adjust the first line to `^(sidney|othersubdomain|anothersubdomain)\.mywebsite\.com...`.

Comment: it is ok, tnx, can u also tell me how to get subdomain and put it after domain name, like i show at the top?